# angularjs - copy common properties from one object to another

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I have a controller like this:

```
CheckoutController = function() {
    $scope.Profile = {
        firstname : 'Ruchir',
        middlename : 'Shakun',
        lastname : 'Gupta',
        email : 'ruchir@example.com',
        cellphone : '9876543210'
    }

    $scope.BillingDetails = {
        firstname : undefined,
        middlename : undefined,
        lastname : undefined,
        addressline : undefined,
        city : undefined,
        zipcode : undefined
    }

    $scope.update = function() {
        // I want to write some awesome code here as explained below
    }
}
```

Now, in the `$scope.update` function; I want to write something that should copy '**only common properties**' i.e. `firstname`, `middlename`, and `lastname` from `$scope.Profile` to `$scope.BillingDetails`.

I tried `angular.copy` and `angular.extend` but,

- `angular.extend` merges `$scope.BillingDetails` and `$scope.Profile`.
  So I get `email` and `cellphone` properties in `$scope.BillingDetails` as
  well -- what I don't want.
- `angular.copy` overwrites
  `$scope.BillingDetails` and I lose `addressline`, `city` and
  `zipcode` from `$scope.BillingDetails` -- what I don't want.

What I want my `update` function to do is it should make `$scope.BillingDetails` equal to below object:

```
{
    firstname : 'Ruchir',
    middlename : 'Shakun',
    lastname : 'Gupta',
    addressline : undefined,
    city : undefined,
    zipcode : undefined    
}
```

This scenario is just an example. To shorten the length of my question, I have mentioned 5-6 properties only. In fact, I have to deal with more than 20 properties and all are dynamic. So it won't work for me by copying one-by-one properties `firstname`, `middlename` and `lastname` from `Profile` to `BillingDetails`. 
What can I do?

Comment: How about `$scope.BillingDetails.firstname = $scope.Profile.firstname`?

Comment: You could create an additional json object with needed properties and set the values. So you can `$scope.BillingDetails` extend with this additional json object. Maybe not beautiful but it can help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may have luck with something like this:

```
$scope.update = function() {
  _update($scope.Profile, $scope.BillingDetails);
}

function _update(srcObj, destObj) {
  for (var key in destObj) {
    if(destObj.hasOwnProperty(key) && srcObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      destObj[key] = srcObj[key];
    }
  }
}
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dQV9QmYsLNdQbULvQtr4?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks! IMHO, using `hasOwnProperty` is better than the solution given by @Tip-Sy

Comment: Cheers - although he was kind enough to provide an explanation with his code as well! ;) Hopefully the above is still fairly self-explanatory.

Comment: Just to clarify in case it helps someone: either use of `myObj.hasOwnProperty('propertyName')` or `'propertyName' in myObj` would have worked on existing properties without needing to check them for `null` or `undefined`, etc; however using `hasOwnProperty` will ignore an obj's inherited properties, unlike `in`, which is usually what you want.

Answer (score 4):

Simple. Just assign them like this:

```
$scope.update = function() {
    $scope.BillingDetails.firstname = $scope.Profile.firstname;
    $scope.BillingDetails.middlename = $scope.Profile.middlename;
    $scope.BillingDetails.lastname = $scope.Profile.lastname;
}
```

I really can't think of a more straightforward method of copying a couple of properties from one object to another.

Since you need to copy more than 3 properties, you could try this:

```
$scope.update = function() {
    // Add the properties you want to copy to this array.
    var properties = ['firstname', 'middlename', 'lastname'];
    for(var i = 0; i < properties.length; i++){
         $scope.BillingDetails[properties[i]] = $scope.Profile[properties[i]];
    }
}
```

Or, pass the array as a parameter:

```
$scope.update = function(properties) {
    for(var i = 0; i < properties.length; i++){
         $scope.BillingDetails[properties[i]] = $scope.Profile[properties[i]];
    }
}

$scope.update(['firstname', 'middlename', 'lastname']);
```

Comment: Sorry but this is just an example. To shorten the length of my question, I have mentioned 5-6 properties only. I have to deal with more than 20 properties and all are dynamic. So it won't work for me in this way. Anyways, thanks for trying to help me!

Comment: Oh, you should've mentioned that in the question. I'll see if I can write something up.

Comment: Sorry, I'm really newbie in StackOverflow that's why. I'm going to edit the question.

Comment: @RuchirGupta: I've added a possible solution to copy a specific list of properties.

Comment: IMHO it would be much better passing the attributes array in the update function, $scope.update = function(attrs)..., will be much more flexible and reusable

Comment: @alou can you please explain more?

Comment: @RuchirGupta: See my last code block. Just a minor tweak.

Comment: @Cerbrus Thanks! I think we can get `properties` array dynamically by iterating a loop through the properties in `BillingDetails` and check if the similar property also exist in `Profile`

Comment: @Cerbrus i think you need to use property names in the loop, not index

Comment: @alou: Eh, no. When iterating an array there is no such thing as "property names". You just use `for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){array[i]}`

Comment: @RuchirGupta: Another detail you should've mentioned... In that case, Tip-Sy's answer should work...

Comment: @Cerbrus You're right, OP was missing many details in his question. I tried to guess what he really wanted, and that's how I came up with an alternative answer. But yours deserves an upvote too, here you are!

Comment: @Tip-Sy and Cerbrus : Thanks guys for suggestions! I've edited the question with clear explanations what I missed on my first go!

Answer (score 3):

In fact, you try to update `BillingDetails` with values of `Profile`, for properties they both have in common right?

If you can change the default values of BillingDetails with `null` instead of `undefined`, you can try this code:

```
$scope.BillingDetails = {
    firstname : null,
    middlename : null,
    lastname : null,
    addressline : null,
    city : null,
    zipcode : null
}

$scope.update = function() {
    for(var key in $scope.Profile) {
        if(typeof $scope.BillingDetails[key] !== 'undefined') {
            $scope.BillingDetails[key] = $scope.Profile[key];
        }
    }
}
```